# What is the best way to Deserialize “Serialized Protobuf” in objective-c which is generated using C# protobuf-net

Tags: c#, c++, objective-c, .net, protocol-buffers

I have a Class that contains objects, arrays, int, and string too.

```
public class Template
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string name;
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public tempClass contour;
        [ProtoMember(3)]
        .
        .
        .
  }

//And here is the Serializing code (Using protobuf-net)
 using (var file = File.Create("Templates.bin"))
            {
                Serializer.Serialize<Template[]>(file, tempArray);
            }
```

I know it can be deserializeable using Objective-c. i tried some solution but did not succeeded yet.

have anyone done this before? is that better to use XML instead of Protobuf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will map to (in .proto terms):

```proto
message templateWrapper {
    repeated template items = 1;
}
message template {
    optional string name = 1;
    optional tempClass contour = 2;
    // ...
}
message tempClass {
    // ...
}
```

And then deserialize as a single `templateWrapper`, which will have multiple `items`.

Note that all of the .proto schema except for the `templateWrapper` should be available via `Serializer.GetProto<Template>()`.

Comment: More details please ! how to create ".proto"? what's that?

Comment: @HazemAbdullah .proto is the schema definition language used by many protobuf implementations; for any given implementation, there is usually a tool ("protoc", "protogen", or something like that) which accepts text .proto files as input, and output platform/language/library-specific files as output; you can refer to [this page](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns) to locate implementations for your chosen platform

Comment: @HazemAbdullah there's an objc example [here](https://code.google.com/p/metasyntactic/wiki/ProtocolBuffers) - look for `protoc`

Comment: @HazemAbdullah as for "how to create '.proto'?" - either: write it by hand, or (as noted above) use `Serializer.GetProto<T>();`